# Export Users with custom fields?

Tags: 7, entities, users, database

I need to set up a semi-regular export of people who have signed up on our website. We're using Drupal 7. I can do a simple export of the Users table, but that doesn't include the additional custom fields we've added.

Is there a module already available in D7 that handles exporting the user database with the custom fields associated with these records?

If not, is there a simple query I can do to identify the custom fields associated with the registration process at runtime? I'd like the export to still work if my customer decides to add a new field.

Comment: How were these custom fields added? I've found the [Profile CSV](http://drupal.org/project/profile_csv) module helpful, though I'm not sure about a D7 status it could be a useful starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of any contrib module that would do this, but I can think of a somewhat simple custom module solution.

Create a custom module that has a [hook_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) call back to a form that you've built with the [form api](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7) that has a submit button that says "Generate Report".

Make sure to create a corresponding permission with [hook_permission](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7) so only users of your choice can access this form.

Then in the submit just run a query ( using [db_query](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--database.inc/function/db_query/7) ) on the users table to get all uid's, then iterate thru each uid to load the full user with [user_load](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_load/7) and build a CSV row with the fields you want, or all fields.  After building the entire csv save it somewhere on the server with a timestamp and link the user to it, or just stream it back to them as a download.

Answer (score 4):

I know that this question has already been answered, but thought I'd point out the [Views Data Export](http://drupal.org/project/views_data_export) module for anyone looking for a contributed solution rather than a bespoke one. This module allows you to define Views that generate CSV files for export. We're using this with Drupal 7 for a client so that they can export all users and their associated custom fields. It's working well.

Comment: Views Data Export module has some performance issues because of the way Views handles user entities. If you need anything that scales, this is probably not the way to go.

Comment: There is the batched export option which should resolve this  issue. Check it inside the "views data export" display options.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to consider for addressing these requirements is the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module.

You would use its report writing features (such as its WYSIWYG report writer and/or it's query builder) to first create a report that fits your needs. The result of it could be a tabular output and/or graph. After the report content matches the specifications, you could save it as (e.g.) a CSV file, or XLS, or DOC, or ...

Here is a quote from one of the forena community docu pages, i.e. [Reasons for considering Forena](https://www.drupal.org/node/2360187):

> Reports created by Forena (combined with SVGGraph and mPDF) can be
>   saved (exported) as PDF documents with embedded graphs. Other
>   supported formats for saving a report are CSV, XLS, DOC, HTML, etc.

The Forena [Video demos and tutorials](https://www.drupal.org/node/2360187) contain quite some links to live demos.