# import-users-with-custom-fields

Tags: entities, users, importing-exporting

[Export Users with custom fields?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4213/export-users-with-custom-fields)
I found this Q&A,a resolved Q.but I want to import the users in another sites ?

Comment: What do you mean in another site?  In a non-Drupal site?

Comment: no,another drupal site

Comment: So you want to migrate users form one site to another?